# Snake console game in C++

Tags: c++, console, windows, c++17, snake-game

I reviewed this question to a snake game console implementation:
[My first C++ game (snake console game)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219645/my-first-c-game-snake-console-game/219658#219658)

I enjoyed refactoring this code and presenting a solution using more C++ features/classes. I ended up rewriting this project from scratch.

My aim was to make the code easy and maintainable to read. Also, I tried to seperate the IO with the console from the logic because maybe I want to use the logic to port the game from console to QT-GUI as another excercise later.

I wonder what can be still be improved in the code?

Is the code easy to read for you/easy to follow?

Are there any bad practices?

Things which can possible be improved:

- Currently, we are not portable. `ConsoleOperations.cpp` uses Windows specified header. Is there an easy way to enable Linux/Mac aswell?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() 
try {
    snakeGame::runGame();
    return 0;
}
catch (...) {
    std::wcerr << "unknown error " << "\n";
    std::wcin.get();
}
```

**Game.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace snakeGame {

    void runGame();
}

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    class Board; // fwd delaration

    bool askUserToEndGame();

    void pauseUntilPauseKeyPressedAgain();

    void printBoardWithStats(const Board& board, long long score, int delay);

    void waitFor(int milliseconds);

    void printGameOverWithScore(int score);

}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"

#include "Snake.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include "ConsoleOperations.h"
#include "SnakeDirection.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace snakeGame {

    using namespace impl;

    void runGame()
    {
        for (;;) {

            if (askUserToEndGame()) {
                return;
            }

            constexpr auto fieldWidth = 40;
            constexpr auto fieldHeight = 15;

            Board board{ fieldWidth, fieldHeight };
            board.updateSnakePosition();
            board.placeFood();
            SnakeDirection snakeDirection = SnakeDirection::right;

            long long score{ 0 };
            long long points{ 100 };
            auto delay(300);

            bool wasPausedInLastLoop{ false };
            for (;;) {
                putCursorToStartOfConsole();
                printBoardWithStats(board, score, delay);

                if (wasPausedInLastLoop) {
                    // If we don't do this and print pause to the console by 
                    // pressing p during the game the pause statement will 
                    // still be printed because  during the game the pause 
                    // statement will still be printed because during the game 
                    // the pause statement will still be printed because 
                    // during the game the pause statement will still be 
                    // printed because we start printing from the beginning of
                    // the console and now the total string printed to the 
                    // console would be one row lower.
                    std::wcout << L"                                     \n";
                    wasPausedInLastLoop = false;
                }

                if (keyWasPressed()) {
                    auto key = getKey();

                    if (key == 'p') {
                        wasPausedInLastLoop = true;
                        std::wcout << L"#####PAUSED#####\n";
                        pauseUntilPauseKeyPressedAgain();
                    }
                    else {
                        snakeDirection = updateDirection(key, snakeDirection);
                    }
                }

                board.moveSnake(snakeDirection);

                if (board.snakeHitFood()) {
                    board.eatFood();
                    board.growSnake();
                    board.placeFood();
                    score += points;
                    points *= 2;
                    delay -= 5;
                }
                else if (board.snakeHitWall() || board.snakeHitSnake()) {
                    break;
                }
                board.updateSnakePosition();

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ delay });
            }

            printGameOverWithScore(score);
        }
    }
}

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    bool askUserToEndGame()
    {
        clearScreen();
        while (true) {

            auto choice{ 0 };
            std::wcout << L"1. Play\n";
            std::wcout << L"2. Quit\n";
            std::wcin >> choice;

            if (choice == 1) {
                return false;
            }

            else if (choice == 2) {
                return true;
            }

            else {
                std::wcout << L"Invalid input!";
                std::wcin.get();
                clearScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    void pauseUntilPauseKeyPressedAgain()
    {
        for (;;) {
            if (keyWasPressed) {

                auto key = getKey();

                if (key == 'p') {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void printBoardWithStats(const Board& board, long long score, int delay)
    {
        std::wcout << L"Score:" << score << '\n';
        std::wcout << L"Delay:" << delay << "ms  \n";
        std::wcout << board;
        std::wcout << L"Use 'w, a, s, d' to change directions\n";
    }

    void waitFor(int milliseconds)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{ milliseconds });
    }

    void printGameOverWithScore(int score)
    {
        clearScreen();
        std::wcout << L"Game over!\n";
        std::wcout << L"Score: " << score << '\n';
        std::wcin.clear();
        std::wcin.ignore(120, '\n');
        std::wcin.get();
    }
}
```

**Board.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Snake.h"

#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iosfwd>

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    enum class SnakeDirection;

    struct Element {
        bool hasSnakeSegment{ false };
        bool hasSnakeHead{ false };
        bool hasWall{ false };
        bool hasFood{ false };
    };

    class Board
    {
    public:
        Board(int width, int height);

        void placeFood();
        void updateSnakePosition();
        bool snakeHitFood() const;
        void eatFood();
        void growSnake();
        bool snakeHitWall() const;
        bool snakeHitSnake() const;
        void moveSnake(SnakeDirection snakeDirection);

        void debugPrintSnakeCoordinates();
    private:
        std::vector<std::vector<Element>> initFieldWithWalls(int width, int height);
        void removeOldSnakePosition(const std::vector<SnakeSegment>& body);
        void addNewSnakePosition(const std::vector<SnakeSegment>& body);

        Snake mSnake;
        std::vector<std::vector<Element>> mField;

        std::random_device mRandomDevice;
        std::default_random_engine mGenerator;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mWidthDistribution;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mHeightDistribution;

        friend std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const Board& obj);
    };

    std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const Board& obj);

}
```

**Board.cpp**

```
#include "Board.h"

#include "SnakeDirection.h"

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>;

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    Board::Board(int width, int height)
        : mSnake{ width, height },
        mField{ initFieldWithWalls(width, height) },
        mRandomDevice{},
        mGenerator{ mRandomDevice() },
        mWidthDistribution{ 1, width - 2 },
        mHeightDistribution{ 1, height - 2 }
    {
    }

    void Board::updateSnakePosition()
    {
        auto snakeBody = mSnake.getBody();

        removeOldSnakePosition(snakeBody);
        addNewSnakePosition(snakeBody);
    }

    bool Board::snakeHitFood() const
    {
        auto pos = mSnake.getBody()[0].pos;
        return mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasFood;
    }

    void Board::eatFood()
    {
        auto pos = mSnake.getBody()[0].pos;
        mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasFood = false;
    }

    void Board::growSnake()
    {
        mSnake.grow();
    }

    bool Board::snakeHitWall() const
    {
        auto pos = mSnake.getBody()[0].pos;
        return mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasWall;
    }

    bool Board::snakeHitSnake() const
    {
        auto pos = mSnake.getBody()[0].pos;
        return mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasSnakeSegment;
    }

    void Board::moveSnake(SnakeDirection snakeDirection)
    {
        switch (snakeDirection) {
        case SnakeDirection::right:
            mSnake.moveRight();
            break;

        case SnakeDirection::down:
            mSnake.moveDown();
            break;

        case SnakeDirection::left:
            mSnake.moveLeft();
            break;

        case SnakeDirection::up:
            mSnake.moveUp();
            break;
        }
    }

    void Board::debugPrintSnakeCoordinates()
    {
        auto body = mSnake.getBody();

        for (auto i = 0; i < body.size(); ++i) {

            auto pos = body[i].pos;

            std::wcout << "nr:" << i << "x:" << pos.x << "\t" << "y:" << pos.y << "\t";

            auto field = mField[pos.y][pos.x];

            if (field.hasSnakeHead) {
                std::wcout << L"Head\t";
            }
            else {
                std::wcout << L"    \t";
            }
            if (field.hasSnakeSegment) {
                std::wcout << L"Body\n";
            }
            else {
                std::wcout << L"    \n";
            }
        }
    }

    void Board::placeFood()
    {
        for (;;) {
            auto x = mWidthDistribution(mGenerator);
            auto y = mHeightDistribution(mGenerator);

            if (!mField[y][x].hasSnakeHead &&
                !mField[y][x].hasSnakeSegment) {
                mField[y][x].hasFood = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<Element>> Board::initFieldWithWalls(int width, int height)
    {
        std::vector<Element> row(width, Element{});
        std::vector<std::vector<Element>> field(height, row);

        Element wall{ false, false, true, false };

        std::fill(field[0].begin(), field[0].end(), wall);
        std::fill(field[field.size() - 1].begin(), field[field.size() - 1].end(), wall);

        for (auto it_row = field.begin() + 1; it_row < field.end() - 1; ++it_row) {
            (*it_row)[0] = wall;
            (*it_row)[it_row->size() - 1] = wall;
        }
        return field;
    }

    void Board::removeOldSnakePosition(const std::vector<SnakeSegment>& body)
    {
        auto first{ true };
        for (const auto& snakeSegment : body) {
            auto prev = snakeSegment.prev;

            if (first) {
                mField[prev.y][prev.x].hasSnakeHead = false;
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                mField[prev.y][prev.x].hasSnakeSegment = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Board::addNewSnakePosition(const std::vector<SnakeSegment>& body)
    {
        auto first{ true };
        for (const auto& snakeSegment : body) {
            auto pos = snakeSegment.pos;

            if (first) {
                mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasSnakeHead = true;
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                mField[pos.y][pos.x].hasSnakeSegment = true;
            }
        }
    }


    std::wostream& operator<<(std::wostream& os, const Board& obj)
    {
        for (const auto& row : obj.mField) {
            for (const auto& element : row) {
                if (element.hasSnakeSegment) {
                    os << L'o';
                }
                else if (element.hasSnakeHead) {
                    os << L'@';
                }
                else if (element.hasWall) {
                    os << L'#';
                }
                else if (element.hasFood) {
                    os << L'*';
                }
                else {
                    os << L' ';
                }
            }
            os << '\n';
        }
        return os;
    }

}
```

**Snake.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Point.h"

#include <vector>

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    struct SnakeSegment
    {
        Point pos{ 0 , 0 };
        Point prev{ pos };
    };

    class Snake
    {
    public:
        Snake(int boardWidth, int boardHeight);

        std::vector<SnakeSegment> getBody() const;

        void moveRight();
        void moveDown();
        void moveLeft();
        void moveUp();
        void grow();

    private:
        void safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement();
        void moveRemainingElements();

        std::vector<SnakeSegment> mBody;
    };

    std::vector<SnakeSegment> initSnake(int fieldWidth, int fieldHeight);

}
```

**Snake.cpp**

```
#include "Snake.h"

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    Snake::Snake(int fieldWidth, int fieldHeight)
        :mBody{ initSnake(fieldWidth, fieldHeight) }
    {
    }

    std::vector<SnakeSegment> Snake::getBody() const
    {
        return mBody;
    }


    void Snake::moveRight()
    {
        safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement();
        ++mBody[0].pos.x;
        moveRemainingElements();
    }

    void Snake::moveDown()
    {
        safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement();
        ++mBody[0].pos.y;
        moveRemainingElements();
    }

    void Snake::moveLeft()
    {
        safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement();
        --mBody[0].pos.x;
        moveRemainingElements();
    }

    void Snake::moveUp()
    {
        safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement();
        --mBody[0].pos.y;
        moveRemainingElements();
    }

    void Snake::grow()
    {
        SnakeSegment newTail;
        newTail.pos.x = mBody[mBody.size() - 1].prev.x;
        newTail.pos.y = mBody[mBody.size() - 1].prev.y;
        mBody.push_back(newTail);
    }

    void Snake::safeCurrentPosToLastOfFirstElement()
    {
        mBody[0].prev.x = mBody[0].pos.x;
        mBody[0].prev.y = mBody[0].pos.y;
    }

    void Snake::moveRemainingElements()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < mBody.size(); ++i) {
            mBody[i].prev.x = mBody[i].pos.x;
            mBody[i].prev.y = mBody[i].pos.y;
            mBody[i].pos.x = mBody[i - 1].prev.x;
            mBody[i].pos.y = mBody[i - 1].prev.y;
        }
    }


    std::vector<SnakeSegment> initSnake(int boardWidth, int boardHeight)
    {
        auto x = boardWidth / 2;
        auto y = boardHeight / 2;
        std::vector<SnakeSegment> body{
            SnakeSegment{ x, y },
            SnakeSegment{ x - 1, y },
        };
        return body;
    }

}
```

**Point.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    struct Point {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

}
```

**SnakeDirection.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    enum class SnakeDirection {
        up, right, down, left
    };

}
```

**ConsoleOperations.h**

```
#pragma once

// Non portable. At the moment only windows works

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    enum class SnakeDirection;

    void putCursorToStartOfConsole();

    void clearScreen();

    bool keyWasPressed();

    char getKey();

    SnakeDirection updateDirection(char c, SnakeDirection direction);
}
```

**ConsoleOperations.cpp**

```
#include "ConsoleOperations.h"

#include "SnakeDirection.h"

#include <cstdlib>

//#ifdef _WIN32
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
//#else 
//  //Assume POSIX
//#endif

namespace snakeGame::impl {

    void putCursorToStartOfConsole()
    {
        //#ifdef _WIN32
        HANDLE hOut;
        COORD Position;

        hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

        Position.X = 0;
        Position.Y = 0;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hOut, Position);
        //#else 
        //  //Assume POSIX
        //#endif
    }


    void clearScreen()
    {
        //#ifdef _WIN32
        std::system("cls");
        //#else
        //  // Assume POSIX
        //  std::system("clear");
        //#endif
    }

    bool keyWasPressed()
    {
        //#ifdef _WIN32
        return static_cast<bool>(_kbhit());
        //#else
            // Assume POSIX
        //#endif
    }

    char getKey()
    {
        //#ifdef _WIN32
        return _getch();
        //#else
            // Assume POSIX
        //#endif
    }

    SnakeDirection updateDirection(char c, SnakeDirection direction)
    {
        switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            if (direction != SnakeDirection::right) {
                direction = SnakeDirection::left;
            }
            break;

        case 'w':
            if (direction != SnakeDirection::down) {
                direction = SnakeDirection::up;
            }
            break;

        case 'd':
            if (direction != SnakeDirection::left) {
                direction = SnakeDirection::right;
            }
            break;

        case 's':
            if (direction != SnakeDirection::up) {
                direction = SnakeDirection::down;
            }
            break;
        }
        return direction;
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume snakedirection is a header file, but you might want to make that clearer.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Fixed. Its a header file. I used MSVC2017.

Answer (score 4):

Overall a good job, and much better than the version you answered.

**Better Not to Ignore Warning Messages**
Board.cpp generates 2 warning messages, the first is for a typo on the semicolon on this line:

```
#include <iostream>;
```

The second is for a type mismatch on this line

```
    for (auto i = 0; i < body.size(); ++i) {
```

Auto comes in very handy for some things, but it is best not to abuse it. C++ is not a scripting language and type checking in C++ is a good thing. Use auto to define iterators when looping through a container but use the proper type in other instances. It's generally a good idea for someone who has to maintain the code to know what type an objects is. Unlike C# and some other languages C++ does not have Reflection.

**Inlcude Header Files Within Headers**
The code might be more maintainable if header files such as `Board.h` and `ConsoleOperations.h` included header files for objects they consume such as `SnakeDirection.h` and `Point.h`. As it is now someone using `Board.h` in a new file will run into compiler issues if they haven't already included the proper files.

**Check User Input**
Neither the function `getKey()` nor `updateDirection(key, snakeDirection)` performs adequate error checking, if the user enters an illegal value, the behavior is unknown. It is always good to check user input.