# Two classes to avoid confusion when handling degrees and radians

Tags: c++, unit-conversion, overloading

Experimenting with operator overloading for the first time. Based on my reading, it appears to be a bit of a minefield.

Have I fallen into any traps?

```
namespace Units
{
    class Degree; // Forward declare Degree so it can be passed by reference into Radian.

    /// \class Radian
    /// Encapsulates a double, and used to represent a radian.
    class Radian
    {

    public:
        /// Constructor.
        /// \param radian The  angle (radians).
        Radian(double radian) : angle_(radian) {}

        /// Constructor.
        /// \param degree The  angle (degrees).
        Radian(const Degree& degree);

        /// Function Call Operator.
        /// \return <double> The angle value (radians).
        operator double() const { return angle_; }

    private:
        double angle_;

    };

    /// \class Degree
    /// Encapsulates a degree, and used to represent a degree.
    class Degree
    {
    public:
        /// Constructor.
        /// \param degree The angle value (degrees).
        Degree(double degree) : angle_(degree) {}

        /// Constructor.
        /// \param radian The  angle (radians).
        Degree(const Radian& radian);

        /// Function Call Operator.
        /// \return <double> The angle (degrees).
        operator double() const { return angle_; }

    private:
        double angle_;
    };

    /// Constructor.
    /// Constructor defined outside of class declaration, to allow Degree class to be defined before it.
    /// \param degree The  angle (degrees).
    Radian::Radian(const Degree& degree)
    : angle_(degree * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::DegToRad)
    {}

    /// Constructor.
    /// Constructor defined outside of class declaration, to allow Radian class to be defined before it.
    /// \param radian The  angle (radians).
    Degree::Degree(const Radian& radian)
    : angle_(radian * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::RadToDeg)
    {}

} // namespace Units

#endif // UNITS_H
```

---

EDIT

and initialised in the way:

```
const Units::Degree latitude = 48.8566;
```

Comment: For a more all-encompassing version of the same general idea, you might want to take a look at [Boost Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) sometime.

Comment: The std::chrono library can inspire you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Design

While it might seem that the current design is working fine, I think there are two distinct issues lurking beneath the surface.

#### Issue #1: `operator double`

From what I can tell, the intention behind these unit classes seems to be the prevention of unit mismatches. Providing an access function to the contained value is not a bad idea, but using the **implicit** conversion operator for doing so is probably not the wisest choice here.

Consider the following snippet:

```
auto angle = Degrees{ 180.0 };
auto sine = std::sin(angle);
```

It compiles easy enough, but will then fail silently at runtime. It likely won't even crash the application, but quietly produce values different to those expected.

Of course, this is a contrived case ("`std::sin` is not really in the scope of this library (yet)!"), but nonetheless it shows a problem: As it is, there is hardly any prevention of accidental unit mismatches.

Adding the keyword `explicit` to `operator double()` might help with some of these cases (though not with `std::sin`), but not all of them.

> If this were the only issue, it would be easy to fix with a getter function with a descriptive name (e.g. `getDegrees`).

#### Issue #2: Extensibility

Let's say that in the future, you (as the library developer) want to add another representation for angles (e.g. gons/gradians). Sounds simple, right?

And at that point, it is. Adding one more class according to the given scheme, four more converting constructors, and it is done.

> Someone familiar with the SOLID principles might already spot a code smell in the last sentence: **four more converting constructors**, two of which have to be added to the existing and otherwise rather independent classes `Degrees` and `Radians`, thus violating the Open-Closed part of SOLID.

After that comes another user A of the library and wants to add his own custom angle representation `RepA`. And then comes user B with `RepB`.

And suddenly, we're having twenty converting constructors just for those five classes. And each additional representation is going to add a lot more: For \$N\$ representations, we need \$N \cdot (N - 1)\$ converting constructors to cover all combinations.

> And that is assuming independent developers add converting constructors for each others implementation. Otherwise, `operator double` will again lurk in the shadows, allowing for code to compile that really should not.
>
> ```
> class Gradians {
> public:
>     Gradians(double);
>     Gradians(const Degrees&);
>     Gradians(const Radians&);
>     operator double() const;
>     // ...
> };
>
> class Turns {
> public:
>     Turns(double);
>     Turns(const Degrees&);
>     Turns(const Radians&);
>     operator double() const;
>     // ...
> };
> ```
>
> Now stuff like `auto a = Gons(300.0); auto b = Turns(a);` will actually compile, but produce wrong results (`b == 300.0` instead of `b == 0.75`).

How can we solve this conundrum?

A first step would be to separate the value from its representation(s) by choosing one internal representation which can be converted on demand:

```
class Angle {
public:
    static Angle fromDegrees(double degrees);
    static Angle fromRadians(double radians);

    double radians() const;
    double degrees() const;
private:
    Angle(double radians) : radians_{ radians } {}

    double radians_;
};

Angle Angle::fromDegrees(double degrees) {
    auto radians = degrees * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::DegToRad;
    return Angle{ radians };
}

Angle Angle::fromRadians(double radians) {
    return Angle{ radians };
}

double Angle::degrees() const {
    return radians_ * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::RadToDeg;
}

double Angle::radians() const {
    return radians_;
}
```

As you can see, I chose radians for my internal representation (mostly because that's what the trigonometric functions of the standard libary expect). For adding a new representation, we now only need to add one factory function (`fromXyz(...)`) and one getter function (`xyz()`).

> While this is a lot cleaner (and takes care of some issues), SOLID devotees will not fail to notice that the violation of the Open-Closed principle hasn't been fixed yet, just moved.
>
> To address this, we could introduce a hierarchy of derived classes, but that seems like overkill for this problem.
>
> Another easy solution would be to use templates:
>
> ```
> struct Degrees {
>     static double toRadians(double degrees) {
>         return degrees * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::DegToRad;
>     }
>     static double fromRadians(double radians) {
>         return radians * SoC::Maths::Trigonometry::RadToDeg;
>     }
> };
>
> struct Radians {
>     static double toRadians(double radians) { return radians; }
>     static double fromRadians(double radians) { return radians; }
> };
>
> class Angle {
> public:
>     template<typename Representation>
>     static Angle from(double value) {
>         return Angle{ Representation::toRadian(value) };
>     }
>
>     template<typename Representation>
>     double as() const {
>         return Repreentation::fromRadians(radians_);
>     }
>
> private:
>     Angle(double radians) : radians_{ radians } {}
>
>     double radians_;
> };
>
>  // Usage
>  auto angle = Angle::from<Degrees>(180.0);
>  auto sine = std::sin(angle.as<Radians>());
> ```

Of course, this is far from done, yet:

- Operators for addition, subtraction (angles), multiplication and/or division (scalars) could be overloaded for this `Angle` class
- For demonstration purposes I didn't mark the member functions above `noexcept` or `constexpr`. This should likely be amended.
- Helper functions like `sin`, `cos`, `tan` and similar could be provided for this `Angle` class.
- For the template version: The templates could be restricted to only accept types with correct signatures for `fromRadians` and `toRadians`.

## Implementation

Aside from the design considerations mentioned above, I can add these points for the general implementation:

- Consider marking converting constructors and conversion operators as `explicit`.
- Very likely `sizeof(Degree) == sizeof(double)`, so there probable won't be a benefit for taking a `const Degree&` parameter over just `Degree`.
- I'd suggest checking the precision of the constants ' DegToRad`and`RadToDeg`, especially if calculated on your own. If the precision on these constants is poor, there might be small numeric errors that accumulate over multiple conversions to and fro.
- A comment reads `/// Function Call Operator`: Actually, no, this is a conversion operator. A function call operator would look like this: `double operator()() const`.
- Generally, the comments don't tell me much about anything. Unless there is a hard requirement for them (in which case they should be improved) I'd suggest removing them. In their current form, they are at best visual clutter, and confusing at worst.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to review my code! Thank you.

I did consider using an Angle class, however dismissed it. Currently, I am passing round doubles to represent my angles, however this has lead to much confusion as to whether a function is operating with degrees or radians. My intention with these classes was to remove that ambiguity, and I'm not sure an "Angle" class would do that.

I acknowledge the issues with using an implicit conversion. Is there any other way to allow assignments as per my edit? Or am I wrong to want to be able to do this?

Comment: @pingu The intention behind the Angle class is that you should not need to care about the angle's representation until you explicitly request one. A function taking an Angle parameter doesn't care whether the Angle was initialized from degrees, radians, gons or something else. And if it actually needs the value in a specific representation, it can request it, and it will be converted automatically. (Hint: This might be much easier to use if some of the arithmetic operators are overloaded: 2*alpha is double the angle, regardless of the representation)

Comment: @pingu: A bit more worked out: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/XEOtXY). Take a look at `myFunc` at the bottom: It doesn't care which representation was used to create its inputs, just does some calculations on the angle and passes it on. Only `sin` actually cares about the representation, and then it actually requests it as needed. If you only pass `Angle`s around, you mostly won't even need to care about the actual internal representation, so in my eyes, this is definitely an improvement

Comment: I'd suggest that one could also implement [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) as suggested in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/220619/arkanoid-console-game/221410#221410)

Comment: @pingu You say, "I am passing round doubles to represent my angles, however this has lead to much confusion as to whether a function is operating with degrees or radians." Is there a reason you don't have a convention like the standard library that all functions dealing with angles take radians? Seems like that would solve the issue. Internally a function could do whatever it wants, but externally all angles should be the same representation, usually.

Comment: @Edward: UDF would surely be nice, but would have to be done per representation (e.g. `2.0_rad`, `180_deg`, `200_gons`, `2.0_turns`). I was focusing more on the `Angle` design instead, since it was much more in need of improvement.

Comment: @user1118321: "Internally a function could do whatever it wants, but externally all angles should be the same representation, usually." That is basically what `Angle` helps you to do in an easy-to-use manner. Explicitly deciding on a uniform representation might not always be feasible (e.g. reliance on third party functions).

Answer (score 3):

The two conversion constructors are not declared in the class, nor are they declared `inline`.  If this code is in a header that is included by multiple source files, you'll have an ODR violation, which typically results in a linker error for multiple definitions of a symbol.

Those two constructors should be declared with the `inline` keyword.

```
inline Radian::Radian(const Degree& degree)
// ...

inline Degree::Degree(const Radian& radian)
// ...
```

Comment: many thanks, I will make these changes, and I have learned something.